# Redirect 301 from a known dynamic url to known static url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla, http-status-code-301

A little background - this site is running Joomla and already has SEF urls. Unfortunately, someone else on another site has linked to our site (extensively) using the non-sef url. Joomla will allow both versions of the URL to access the correct page.

I would prefer to do a simple

```
redirect 301 index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50&Itemid=18 http://www.mywebsite.com/anythingiwant.html
```

But this is not so simple, I suspected some of the characters in the first url would need to be escaped but that did not work either. I also put quotations around the first URL with escaped characters and no matter what I do, I cannot redirect that one very specific and dynamic URL to any other page.

Comment: `Redirect` directive cannot match query string. Your only option is to use mod_rewrite -- it can do for sure.

Comment: @LazyOne I forgot to update you on the issue, but I went with your suggestion and used mod_rewrite to test the URL before Joomla did any of it's custom rewrite stuff.

Comment: If it's all solved please post your solution/exact rule as an answer and accept it -- it can be useful for other people with similar problem. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix my SEO issue with this, I installed an SEO module for Joomla that allows me to assign a 'canonical url' meta tag to each article. I put the SEF url in for this meta tag, and Google has re-indexed it accordingly.